# Qual versão do primefaces extensions é compataivel com o primefaces 3.5?

Tags: java, primefaces, primefaces-3.5

Utilizo primefaces 3.5 no meu projeto e pretendo utilizar Primefaces Extension.
Gostaria de saber qual a versão mais nova do Primefaces Extension é é compativel com a versão 3.5 do Primefaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A versão do primefaces extension utilizada com o primefaces 3.5 é 0.7.1.

Comment: valeu demais cara!